# Correct way to specify Meteor package dependencies

Tags: javascript, meteor, package

I am trying to create a new Meteor package that depends on another meteor package. When I try `meteor add mypackage` I get the following error. Why isn't Meteor adding mypackage and pulling in it's dependencies?

```
=> Errors while scanning packages:

While building package 'mypackage':
error: no such package: 'aloha-editor'
```

Here are the package.js and smart.json files from mypackage.

package.js

```
Package.describe({
  summary: "REPLACEME - What does this package (or the original one you're wrapping) do?"
});

Package.on_use(function (api, where) {
  api.add_files('package1.js', ['client', 'server']);
});

Package.on_test(function (api) {
  api.use('aloha-editor', 'client');
  api.use('package1', 'client');

  api.add_files('package1_tests.js', 'client');
});
```

smart.json

```
{
  "name": "package1",
  "description": "REPLACEME - What does this package (or the original one you're wrapping) do?",
  "homepage": "",
  "author": "Your Name <your@email> (http://yoursite)",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "git": "",
  "packages": {
    "aloha-editor": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your dependency seems to be defined correctly. However, you need to run `mrt add mypackage` instead of `meteor add mypackage`. The second command only uses packages provided with Meteor, while `mrt` has access to the whole Atmosphere repository you're trying to use.

Comment: I don't know if this relevant but `mypackage` is just a local dir inside my packages directory. `mrt add mypackage` gives me the following error.

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/meteor.js:154
          throw "Error running a command: " + error;
                                            ^
Error running a command: Error: Command failed: => Errors while scanning packages:

While building package `mypackage`:
error: no such package: 'aloha-editor'

Comment: In that case, you don't use any of these commands. Simply add the local package name to `.meteor/packages` file. The error is expected, by the way, if `aloha-editor` is not present in the Atmosphere.

Comment: When I just add `mypackage` to `.meteor/packages` I get this error on `meteor run`. => Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Errors prevented startup:

While building package `package1`:
error: no such package: 'aloha-editor'

The `aloha-editor` package is supposedly present in the Atmosphere.

Comment: Try running `mrt` instead of `meteor`. Alternatively, run `mrt install` before you start the app.